# Can't add Service Reference Properly

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, azure

I have a notificationService under 443 port but when i try to add it to windows phone 7 service reference I can't, so is it can be linked that the fact that my service is deployed under 443 port.

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to http://localhost:443/NotificationService.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
<services>
  <service name="Project.Services.NotificationService"
           behaviorConfiguration="notificationservicebehavior">
    <endpoint name="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="Project.Services.INotificationService"
              address="http://127.0.0.1:443/NotificationService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="notificationservicebehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: you need to provide more info. "i can't" doesn't tell us much. what step is failing, what are the errors (if any), what have you tried so far to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a self signed certificate or one that's not from any of [these authorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) you'll need to install this on the device.

There are only 2 ways to install 3rd party certificates on the device and neither can currently be done through code:

> Installing certificates via Windows®
> Internet Explorer®
> A certificate can
> be posted on a website and made
> available to users through a
> device-accessible URL that they can
> use to download the certificate. When
> a user accesses the page and taps the
> certificate, it opens on the device.
> The user can inspect the certificate,
> and if they choose to continue the
> certificate is installed on the
> device.
>
> Installing certificates via email
> The certificate installer on
> Windows Phone 7 supports .cer, .p7b,
> and .pfx files. When installing
> certificates via email, make sure your
> mail filters do not block .cer files.
> Certificates that are sent via email
> appear as message attachments. When a
> certificate is received, a user can
> tap to review the contents and then
> tap to install the certificate.
> Typically, when an identity
> certificate is installed the user is
> prompted for the passphrase that
> protects it.

You'll have to get the user to perform one of these actions before the app will work with the certificate.

From [Windows Phone 7 and Certificates_FINAL_121610.pdf](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfad6c2f-988a-4b09-9e3b-58bfc9ac0447)